# Error en Visual Studio 2019 HRESULT E_FAIL E

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Estoy teniendo un problema con el `Visual Studio 2019`, a la hora de querer agregar una referencia me salta el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probé recompilando la solución, poniendo a reparar el visual, desintalandolo y reinstalandolo y sigue sin resolverse.

Si alguien le paso algo parecido y me puede dar una mano se lo agradecería mucho. Saludos.

Comment: Que referencia es?, de NuGet, una dll..?. Indica algo mas de información por favor. También indica que tipo de proyecto es, .NET Core o .NET Framework?.

Comment: .NET Framework. Y la referencia no puse por que ni siquiera llego a poder entrar a la interfaz para elegir la referencia. Cuando presiono Click derecho--> Agregar Referencias me salta el error que les mencione. También instale el Visual Studio 2017 Profesional y me tira el mismo error. El error salta en cualquier lugar que quiera agregar una referencia, no es en un lugar puntual.